# Removing non-similar rows in two data-frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I currently have the following dataframes:

```
> results1
         Estimate  Std. Error     t value     Pr(>|t|)
b32 -0.6715123443 0.075520421 -8.89179819 4.787171e-16
b31 -0.5980455182 0.071979445 -8.30855978 1.844544e-14
b30  0.4416429283 0.093555787  4.72063719 4.567844e-06
b29 -0.4147988548 0.068768882 -6.03178131 8.370384e-09
b28  0.2111363424 0.083077926  2.54142531 1.184315e-02
b10  0.0035913631 0.032030594  0.11212290 9.108450e-01
b9  -0.0014542660 0.005297667 -0.27451065 7.839920e-01
b8   0.0657446181 0.020887493  3.14755913 1.913415e-03
b7  -0.0289678980 0.033560155 -0.86316341 3.891416e-01
b6   0.0002044789 0.006934281  0.02948812 9.765064e-01
b5   0.0034210947 0.011367978  0.30094136 7.637900e-01
b4  -0.0033941213 0.004618224 -0.73494074 4.632865e-01
b1   0.0752108810 0.041080300  1.83082600 6.870121e-02
```

and

```
> betas1
          betas1
b33  0.000000000
b32 -0.503278255
b31  0.347831676
b30 -0.288778978
b29  0.172110468
b28  0.002378104
b27  0.000000000
b26  0.000000000
b25  0.000000000
b24  0.000000000
b23  0.000000000
b22  0.000000000
b21  0.000000000
b20  0.000000000
b19  0.000000000
b18  1.474562637
b16  0.000000000
b15  0.000000000
b14  0.000000000
b13  0.000000000
b12  0.000000000
b11  0.000000000
b10  0.001442897
b9   0.148189325
b8  -0.006230467
b7   0.076707017
b6  -4.921328653
b5  -2.737342353
b4   3.428674629
b3   0.000000000
b2   0.000000000
b1   0.003284209
b34  0.000000000
```

I am trying to eventually cbind these dataframes together; however, to do this I am trying to get rid of all the values (i.e., row names) in `betas1` that are not in results 1.  I have tried `which` function which doesn't appear to be working, and also `betas1<-results1[!(results1 %in% betas1)]`, but this also appears to not be working.  Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly? What aspect of betas1 are you hoping to not replicate? How do you intend on binding the dfs together? More detail would be helpful.

Comment: See Simon Mills's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the merge function will merge two dataframes together based on shared values of a specified column (in this case row.names).

```
df <- merge(results1, betas2, by="row.names")
```

Comment: That worked; however, do you know how I could keep the original order of results1?

Comment: To override merge's default reordering add "sort = FALSE"